# i want to use AWS rekognition from python and am getting that error when i follow all the steps

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services

```
for bucket in boto3.resource('s3').buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

> ````
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "C:\Users\icode\PycharmProjects\AWS\venv\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\collection.py", line 83, in __iter__
>     for page in self.pages():
>   File "C:\Users\icode\PycharmProjects\AWS\venv\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\collection.py", line 161, in pages
>     pages = [getattr(client, self._py_operation_name)(**params)]
>   File "C:\Users\icode\PycharmProjects\AWS\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 357, in _api_call
>     return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
>   File "C:\Users\icode\PycharmProjects\AWS\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
>     raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (NotSignedUp) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Your account is not signed up for the S3 service. You must sign up before you can use S3.```
> ````

Comment: Could you please clarify where you are running this code (EC2 or your own computer)? Have you obtained AWS credentials for your program?

Comment: upload your full code.

Answer (score 0):

You've not signed up for S3.  You'll need to visit the AWS Console first, sign up, and wait for the activation email.  See [the documentation for more details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/SigningUpforS3.html).

Answer (score 0):

take a look at your error message, on the last line it says your are not signed up

````
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (NotSignedUp) when calling the ListBuckets operation:
Your account is not signed up for the S3 service. You must sign up before you can use S3.```
````

what you need to do is:

[image]

from [s3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/SigningUpforS3.html)